# PHP require realpath - Failed opening required

Tags: php, path, include, require

I am trying to `require`/`include` a file by relative path. The paths exist and all rights are checked. The script to be included is readable and can be accessed via URL in browser...

However, I am receiving errors/warnings that it failed to open. Both the calling script and the file to be included are on the same server.

Caller relative:

`/devel/phi/dev/appcenter-head/appcenter/application/nm/index.php`

Caller location:

`/home/devel/wwwroot/phi/dev/appcenter-head/appcenter/application/nm`

Require relative:

`/devel/nm/dev/http-api/http-api/src/httpapi.inc.php`

Require location:

`/home/devel/wwwroot/nm/dev/http-api/http-api/src`

What I tried:

```
$strHttpApiUrl = "/devel/nm/dev/http-api/http-api/index.php";
$strFile = "/src/httpapi.inc.php";
$strDirName = dirname( $strHttpApiUrl );
$strRealpath = realpath( $strDirName . $strFile );
require_once $strRealpath;
```

Fails with: `PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/devel/wwwroot/phi/dev/appcenter-head/appcenter/application/nm) [<a href='function.require-once'>functio
n.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/devel/wwwroot/phi/dev/appcenter-head/appcenter/application/nm/class/TWinLogin.php`

Also fails with: `PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/opt/nm/appcenter40-server-php53/lib/php')`

Also tried plain including the string URL or using absolute path...

How can I include that file?

---

**EDIT**:

This successfully includes the file:

`require_once '/home/devel/wwwroot/nm/dev/http-api/http-api/src/httpapi.inc.php';`

So how can I get that working path, assume I get the following relative path:

`/devel/nm/dev/http-api/http-api/index.php`

Comment: remove space in `TWinLogin.ph p` ?

Comment: That was just from terminal copying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

realpath tries to get real path in file system -- absolute path. So it most possibly starts with slash.

If your resulting path starts with slash and php tries to require/include it, most possibly it will think that its' absolute. And if it not see there existing file -- it gives you those error.

If you want to use relative pathes, avoid realpath.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit. Also, I tried some variations without the leading slash - did not work.

Comment: Seomthing like '../../../../etc/../etc/../' ? Prepend it correclty -- I hope you understand the idea.

Comment: Do you know what is relative pathes? For example when we are at /home/a/b/c, then to get to a we just type in in console "cd ../..". I talk to you about this way.

Comment: Also about "relative". When path starts from slash -- it can't be relative. It can be relative when it starts with one or two dots. In your example both pathes starts with slashes. May be here the problem?

Comment: Sure, I know what a relative path is. My given relative path with file is unknown to me. Now, I want the absolute path to that file. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Emmm... Take some root path and add to it your relative path? I just dont' understand the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. Did not recognize realpath takes absolute path of the system.