# PHP include file by relative path

Tags: php, path, include

This absolute path successfully includes my file `httpapi.inc.php`:

`require_once '/home/devel/wwwroot/nm/dev/http-api/http-api/src/httpapi.inc.php';`

The calling file is:

Caller relative:

`/devel/phi/dev/appcenter-head/appcenter/application/nm/index.php`

Caller location:

`/home/devel/wwwroot/phi/dev/appcenter-head/appcenter/application/nm`

Now, how can I include that same file based on a relative path like:

`/devel/nm/dev/http-api/http-api/index.php`

I must use this path "as is", since it is a config option passed by the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP require realpath - Failed opening required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617524/php-require-realpath-failed-opening-required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require()` and `include()` should operate relative to the configured [include paths](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) and the currently executing script. So, this should work:

```
require_once('src/httpapi.inc.php');
```

To be perfectly precise, though, the current script's working directly is actually designated as one of the include paths in the default configuration. It won't work if you've mucked with it.

> Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means
>   the current directory.

**Regarding your latest edit**, your paths are different enough that it's simpler to just use the full path or add `/home/devel/wwwroot/nm/dev/http-api/http-api/` to your config and use `require_once('src/httpapi.inc.php')`.

Comment: Forgot to add where the calling script is located, please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get that full path? All my attempts using `realpath` failed.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know the path. Just use it and/or put the partial, but absolute, path into your configuration as part of the include path.

Comment: Yes I know the full path now on my own system, but if I is installed somewhere else, I need a functionality that gives me the full path by this relative path.

Comment: Yeah ... I keep trying to understand the scenario you're presenting, and each time I read it I'm more confused about what you're trying to accomplish. If you're allowing users (presumably trusted developers) to submit file-paths for inclusion in processing, they need to provide paths relative to some common root, like `/home/devel/`. Then, take their paths and just concatenate them. `require_once('/home/devel/' . $dev_script)`. Don't try to work miracles to grant devs the ability to specify paths with nothing in common.

Comment: OK. So, you're writing an application that other developers will install - that clarifies things. In that case, as part of their configuration, **make them specify an absolute include path** and/or **make it clear that their includes must live in `./some/path/to/includes` relative to the application**.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider using the include path option or using just absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the document root from the $_SERVER variable:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/nm/dev/http-api/http-api/src/httpapi.inc.php';
```

Comment: This fails with Fatal Error: `Failed opening required '/opt/nm/appcenter40-server-php53/htdocs/nm/
dev/http-api/http-api/src/httpapi.inc.php'`

Answer (score -1):

```
 include "src/httpapi.inc.php";
```